# rtkQuery update cache

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I did not understand how to update the cache without additional requests in the component, in this case I call endpoint getEntity so that the cache key endpoint getEntity + arg is assigned to each entity in the code.

I wrote a [simple example](https://codesandbox.io/s/rtkquery-cache-example-001-ujb55p?file=/src/cache/index.js)

Now I attach the cache key in this way,

```
const Entity = ({ id }) => {
  const res = apiQuery.useGetEntityQuery(id);
  return <div>{JSON.stringify(res.data)}</div>;
};

const Output = ({ Entities }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {Entities &&
        Entities instanceof Array &&
        Entities.map(({ id }) => {
          return <Entity key={id} id={id} />;
        })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

how correct would it be to call api Query.useGetEntityQuery(id) for each element?

Is there a more correct way to work with the cache applicable to this case?

Is it possible to make the code below work and what is needed for this, or is it not necessary to do this?

```
const Output = ({ Entities }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {Entities &&
        Entities instanceof Array &&
        Entities.map(({ id, value }) => {
          return (
            <div key={id}>
              {id}:{value}
            </div>
          );
        })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In RTK Query, each cache entry is completely separate, so you have to write the logic for that yourself if you really need to - although most of the time an additional request does not hurt and that is the main way it is designed to being used.

If you want to do it though, read [Manual Cache Updates](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/manual-cache-updates)

Comment: phry, thanks for the answer. I read your message that an additional request is not superfluous. But to expand my experience, I would like to know if there are alternatives.  I know that without an additional request, updateQueryData does not work with getEntity, this is logical because there is no cache there yet. And I don't understand how to add a cache to endpoint getEntity, without an additional request. And I do not know what best practices exist for this, but since you advised manual cache update as an alternative. If it's not difficult, write the code without an additional request

Comment: At the moment there is no possibility to add a cache entry that did not exist yet. There is an open PR and it will probably be in the next version.